# Negative binomial’s predicted counts are too high with skewed predictors

Tags: regression, distributions, generalized-linear-model, predictive-models, negative-binomial-distribution

I am modeling count data (disease incidence) using negative binomial regression, and a couple of my predictors are extremely right-skewed. When I include these predictors, the model's predicted counts are many orders of magnitude too high for observations with the highest actual counts. I am wondering why these predictors are an issue, i.e. what assumptions I might be violating, and if I should use negative binomial on this data or if I need to find a new approach.

The data I am using are confidential with ~3000 observations, but I made a small dummy data set that replicates the problem (pasted below). Here, variable V1 is the skewed predictor.

```
menbreg realcount v1 v2, exposure(exp) || clust:, irr
predict predcount
```

When I run this STATA code, which is a mixed-effects negative binomial with an exposure, I get predicted values that are very inflated for the largest observed counts.

[image]

This phenomenon happens whether I used fixed or mixed effects, if I try Poisson, if I Z-standardize the offending covariates, if I drop the exposure, and various other model re-specifications. Interestingly, a simple linear regression produces predictions that are all plausible in magnitude! Note also that V1 is highly correlated with the outcome (and similar in scale).

I can reduce the problem by log-transforming the variables, but this seems inelegant because a.) the skewed variables include zeroes, so I have to add a constant before log-transforming; b.) predictions remain somewhat inflated; and c.) I thought there were no assumptions regarding the distribution of independent variables in generalized linear models.

I have not found anything on the internet about this problem, so I suspect I am missing something in asking this question.

I am asking:

1. Why are the predictions so incorrect?
2. What, if any, assumptions I am violating of the negative binomial model?
3. If I am violating assumptions, are there other approaches within the GLM family that I should use instead?

Data:

```
realcount   v1  v2  exp clust
0   0   0.2 10009   1
0   1   0.13    12032   5
0   1   0.43    45012   2
0   0   0.11    11098   2
0   0   0.04    66738   2
0   1   0.63    21592   5
0   0   0.29    21291   8
0   1   0.11    32904   7
0   0   0.05    18294   8
0   0   0.25    78024   2
0   0   0.21    12353   2
0   1   0.2 19878   1
1   0   0.78    44581   2
1   0   0.21    22583   4
1   1   0.53    55839   5
1   2   0.33    78159   8
1   1   0.26    29043   7
1   0   0.44    56781   8
2   1   0.45    54900   4
2   2   0.37    23891   3
2   3   0.53    38902   2
3   4   0.41    57816   8
4   4   0.38    61445   4
5   6   0.41    67899   7
7   4   0.65    48203   2
10  13  0.71    88901   9
10  11  0.5 160982  5
13  9   0.66    78901   3
15  14  0.76    240582  6
21  22  0.69    180327  6
29  23  0.8 198733  6
41  43  0.51    58901   7
52  56  0.67    345928  9
83  90  0.72    87260   1
109 190 0.23    121303  2
113 100 0.93    180923  9
160 200 0.86    90987   9
284 450 0.88    450911  7
426 600 0.37    74342   8
592 500 0.77    541009  2
882 781 0.95    498211  5
1032    1246    0.78    1348821 1
```